# Why is the integer `j` returning a `i`?

Tags: c

```
  //Increment and decrement operators:
  char *s = "iLoveC";
  int j = 0;
  s[j++]; // => "i". Returns the j-th item of s THEN increments value of j.
  j = 0;
  s[++j]; // => "L". Increments value of j THEN returns j-th value of s.
  // same with j-- and --j
```

Some questions on this:

- What stands the `*` on `s` for?
- Why is `j` returning a `i` instead a 0, on the 4th line?
- Why is `j` returning a `l` instead a 1, on the 6th line?

This comes from a simple tutorial for beginners (http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/c/) and I couldn't even understand it. My background is PHP/Javascript/Lisp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But you're telling me that I google on the output of [j++] , while I'm trying to understand it. And it's even from a simple tutorial: http://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/c/ 
If I can't understand a simple tutorial, how am I ever get it then? Hence my question here.

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions. Your questions should be "what do the * is on a type in C? What do ++j do? and etc. Most of those questions can be found here on SO. But mostly you want to read about pointer arithmetics

Comment: @fotanus: https://www.google.nl/search?q=what+do+the+*+is+on+a+type+in+C&oq=what+do+the+*+is+on+a+type+in+C , so how Am I supposed to find an answer? Pointer arithmetics is a good start, thanks for that.

Comment: @ReneFrogertjuh Avoid special characters on google searches. try this one: `what do the asterisk is on a type in C`. [First link for me](http://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F398395%2Fin-c-why-is-the-asterisk-before-the-variable-name-rather-than-after-the-type&ei=nZlwVfC9GcOXgwSBoIGoCA&usg=AFQjCNF2_Aq4LjyW4OyTbD1mW0a8snR_UA&bvm=bv.94911696,d.eXY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The * operator declares s as a pointer. This means that it will contain the address of the variable assigned. Here the value of the pointer s is i i.e, the first element of the string "iLoveC". When you use post increment s[j++] it is equivalent to s[0]='i' but when you use s[++j] it is equivalent to s[1]='L'

See this link http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-pointers-arrays
and start by readind some books.

Comment: Thanks, never realised the characters of the string "iLoveC" was used in a array to access it.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is a lot of overlap between pointers and arrays. The line

```
char *s = "iLoveC";
```

can in this instance be treated as if it were an array of `char` values, similar to

```
char s[7] = {'i', 'L', 'o', 'v', 'e', 'C', '\0'};
```

. In that case, `s[0]` is the character `'i'`, etc.

`s[j++]` uses the post-increment operator on `j`, so that when `j` starts with the value `0`, that is the value used to index the array before `j` is incremented to `1`; the expression is the same as `s[j]; j++`.

`s[++j]` use the pre-increment operator on `j`, where the variable is incremented *before* it is used to index the array; the expression is the same as `++j; s[j]`